# Is latitude/longitutude linear?

Tags: python, math, latitude-longitude, proj

I'm trying to create a grid system three variables: `upper-left.lat`, `upper-left.long` and `lower-right.lat`, `lower-right.long` and `grid-size = 100 meters`. Just to be clear, the `grid-size` represents the width and height of each cell within the grid.

I'm trying to figure it out now is if the lat/long system is linear - depending on the upper-left and lower-right, could the cells be bigger or smaller?

Comment: I don't know what linear means in this context but the cells will have different size.

Comment: Think about the fact that, at the poles, any angle in longitude has no length.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work on the Earth's surface like it would in a Cartesian plane. As latitude takes one further from the Equator, the ratio of meters to longitude varies as the cosine of the latitude.

It is not "linear"

Comment: I thought so. Thank you.